# Array empty when scraping og: meta

Tags: php, metadata, domdocument, meta

I've posted a url into a feed I've created on my homeserver to get all meta data of that url off a website.

The website I've scraped is uk.yahoo.com. I have posted that very link knowing that it infact has an og: meta for that page under that very url.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/130909/y_200_a.png">

<meta name="description" content="News, email....">

<meta property="og:title" content="Yahoo">
```

yet when I look at my console it says the array is empty

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // 
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//*/meta[starts-with(@property, \'og:\')]';
$metas = $xpath->query($query);
$rmetas = array();
foreach($metas as $meta) {

$property = $meta->getAttribute('property');
$content = $meta->getAttribute('content');
$rmetas[$property] = $content;
}
var_dump($rmetas);
```

I then post a news.yahoo.com link and it gets all the og: meta perfect.

Comment: Step 1: don't trust yourself to know what the code does, *verify* what the code does. Print that `$doc`: what's in it? Does it even have the HTML5 meta tags, or did it throw them away because they didn't follow the ancient HTML4.1 rules for self-closing elements? If it does, where are they? Does your xpath even work for that nesting?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans in printing the $doc into my console it is showing no og: content at all.

Comment: I don't understand why in one page I can get the data, but in another I can't within the same website.

Comment: then you should investigate that: save the HTML for both pages, and write a five line script that loads both files, parses both files, and prints the tag set. Empty the <body> tags on both files, so you're just working with the head, and then see what's different between the two.

Comment: @mike honestly,  i don’t follow at all. I’m not really understanding what you mean! I thought the files were already parsed? I don’t know what I’m doing at all. I cannot find anyone that’s had the same issue on the net and any examples to understand my problem.

Comment: I mean if you see two html files and one "works" and the other "doesn't work", investigate that. Find out what their difference is, to gain insight. And you're parsing for <meta> tags so take those two html pages, _save them to .html files using your browser or curl or wget or something_, and then remove everything in the `<body>` tag because none of that is relevant to your problem. This is the start of forming a [mcve], which is an important debugging process to run through before you start asking questions: often, you _can_ find the answer on your own, if you put in that time.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have got it working by changing a few lines in my curl.

Comment: What part? Did you actually solve your question's problem, or did you just make curl grab the html pages? (because that's just curl + the url and then you open the file it saves in a text editor and throw most of it away. Don't try to get curl to do that)

Comment: I removed header [‘’]  and added a referrer if I remember correctly. I’m at work on nights atm, but I will post my answer to the problem and update my question as it may help others, I’m just scouring for the meta title and keywords in the pages through curl via any given url.